# Unable to submit the form on laravel6

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-6

while submit the form  pages using get method, does not send to the controller but I print the link on browsers to get the results, I used gates and policies on web routes, i used pagination of forms as below links, two pages contains

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps

Comment: please help anyone

Answer (score 0):

Please use your form method POST request ,

like this :- `form method="POST" action="{{ route('yourSubmitingRoute') }}"`

Comment: thanks for your reply bro.i tried but not worked @Abdullah Mahi